# How to concatenate strings into one using loop?

Tags: string, lua

can someone help me with string concatenate problem. I read data from register. It's function utf(regAddr, length). I get table with decimal numbers, then I transform it into hex and to string in loop. I need concatenate these strings into one. 
there is not in Lua something like .= operator

```
function utf(regAddr, length)
  stringTable = {} 
  table.insert(stringTable, {mb:readregisters(regAddr-1,length)})

  for key, value in pairs(stringTable) do
    for i=1, length do
      v = value[i]
      v = lmcore.inttohex(v, 4)
      v = cnv.hextostr(v)   
      log(v)
    end  
  end
end

-- function(regAddr, length)
utf(30,20)
```

[image]

Comment: why are you inserting a table into stringTable for each item, why not `table.insert(stringTable, mb:readregisters(regAddr-1,length))`?

Comment: Hello,
I`m inserting a table into stringTable only once. it`s not in loop. I can also read this register as
value1, value2, value3, ... , value20 = mb:readregisters(regAddr-1,20)

but I think better is work with table and loop. I don`t want to have 20 variables.

I need iterate via table and for each variable in table use lmcore.inttohex and cnv.hextostr to get ASCII string. Final text must be "Power Meter" in one variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no append operator for strings. Strings are immutable values.

The `..` operator concatenates two string, producing a third string as a result:

```
local b = "con"
local c = "catenate"
local a = b .. c  -- "concatenate"
```

The `table.concat` function concatenates strings in a table, producing a string result:

```
local t = { "con", "catenate" }
local a = table.concat(t)  -- "concatenate"

local t = { "two", "words" }
local a = table.concat(t, " ") -- "two words"
```

The `string.format` function takes a format pattern with a list of compatible values, producing a string result:

```
local b = 2
local c = "words"
local a = string.format("%i %s", b, c)  -- "2 words"

local t = { 2, "words" }
local a = string.format("%i %s", unpack(t))  -- "2 words"
```

If you are accumulating a lot of strings that you eventually want to concatenate, you can use a table as a temporary data structure and concatenate when you are done accumulating:

```
local t = {}
for i = 1, 1000 do
    table.insert(t, tostring(i))
end
local a = table.concat(t) -- "1234...9991000"
```

For a very large number of strings, you can concatenate incrementally. See [LTN 9: Creating Strings Piece by Piece](http://www.lua.org/notes/ltn009.html) and related discussions.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom, your last piece of code works well and helped me

Answer (score 3):

You should try the [**table.concat**](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-table.concat) method.

Maybe this other question can help you:

- [Lua table.concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477596/lua-table-concat)
- Checkout this tutorial http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableLibraryTutorial

Comment: Hi,
I tried this function but for functions lmcore.inttohex and cnv.hextostr I need number no table.
Some kind of append operator in loop seems to be solution, but I!m not sure how to do it

Answer (score 0):

this code works:

```
function utf(regAddr, length)
    stringTable = {}
    table.insert(stringTable, {mb:readregisters(regAddr-1,length)})

    for key, value in pairs(stringTable) do
        t = {}

        for i=1, length do
            v = value[i]
            v = lmcore.inttohex(v, 4)
            v = cnv.hextostr(v)

            table.insert(t, v)
        end
        a = table.concat(t)

    end

end

-- function(regAddr, length)
utf(30,20)
```